# Entities Not Being Created in Database Using Spring Boot, JPA, MySQL and Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently working on a RESTful backend API using Spring Boot, MySQL for data persistence, JPA for ORM and Spring Data REST to expose the repositories as RESTful endpoints. However, I've run into a problem: the entities I've defined in Java aren't being created as tables in my MySQL database.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nom;
    private String adresseEmail;
    private String motDePasse;
    private String numeroTelephone;
    private String role;

// getters and setters
}
```

I have configured the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property in my application.properties file as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=4443
spring.jpa.database= MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

here pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Transport0001</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Transport0001</name>
    <description>Transport0001</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

logs when i launch the project :

```
2023-06-21T13:15:59.276+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.Transport0001Application           : Starting Transport0001Application using Java 17.0.7 with PID 5728 (C:\Users\master\eclipse-workspace1\Transport0001\target\classes started by master in C:\Users\master\eclipse-workspace1\Transport0001)
2023-06-21T13:15:59.340+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.Transport0001Application           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-21T13:15:59.747+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-21T13:15:59.748+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-21T13:16:02.215+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-06-21T13:16:02.217+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-21T13:16:02.251+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-06-21T13:16:02.286+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-06-21T13:16:02.287+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-21T13:16:02.301+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-21T13:16:04.581+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 4443 (http)
2023-06-21T13:16:04.630+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-21T13:16:04.631+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-21T13:16:04.852+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-21T13:16:04.856+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5103 ms
2023-06-21T13:16:05.619+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-21T13:16:06.263+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.2.Final
2023-06-21T13:16:06.276+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-06-21T13:16:06.733+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-21T13:16:07.260+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-06-21T13:16:07.380+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-21T13:16:07.835+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Receiver class com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getNetworkTimeout()' of interface java.sql.Connection.)
2023-06-21T13:16:07.837+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@6352190f
2023-06-21T13:16:07.840+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-06-21T13:16:08.065+02:00  WARN 5728 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000511: The 5.5.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 5.7.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions.
2023-06-21T13:16:08.101+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.dialect                : HHH035001: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, version: 5.5
2023-06-21T13:16:08.429+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-21T13:16:09.720+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-06-21T13:16:09.744+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-21T13:16:09.847+02:00  WARN 5728 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-06-21T13:16:11.805+02:00  WARN 5728 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: b759bb29-f74e-49ea-8d9b-bb3e07b9e72f

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2023-06-21T13:16:12.196+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@ef58939, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@436b80ed, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3d2e649, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2bd17f0e, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5689f52a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48e8a2e0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3bc86bf8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@7527e759, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2992894d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@23cdc3c1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7498978a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@474e210b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6f32e85e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1f656006, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@533704c5]
2023-06-21T13:16:12.288+02:00  WARN 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2023-06-21T13:16:12.412+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 4443 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-21T13:16:12.434+02:00  INFO 5728 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.Transport0001Application           : Started Transport0001Application in 15.199 seconds (process running for 22.007)
```

Despite this configuration, the user table is not being created in mydatabase. There are no error messages shown in the console, and the application starts up normally.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Checked if the database connection is established correctly.

Verified the entity class for any syntax errors.

Tried different settings for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto.
Unfortunately, none of these steps has resolved my issue. Could anyone provide some guidance on what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have the next project (https://github.com/wilson1234567891962/ProyectoAndes-Backend/tree/main), it creates the automatic tables. maybe you can try with the project that i  have

Comment: Remove `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`, fix the compilation errors (`javax.persistence` -> `jakarta.persistence`), re-run project.

Comment: @Loran - did you check our comments and answers? Please update on any progress you made.

Answer (score 0):

You have way too many starters dependencies in your pom.xml. Some of them are conflicting and causing the Spring Boot auto-configuration to back-off.

1. The best way to start with project dependencies is to use the Spring site https://start.spring.io Select `Maven` and add only `Spring Web`, `Spring Data JPA` and `MySQL` dependencies. Download `pom.xml` and test.
2. Please check if your Entity class has a no-args constructor. I can't see it.
3. Use `com.example` package in all your classes. This will allow Spring smoothly auto-configure JPA.
4. Remove following properties as they will only confuse the auto-configuration. Spring Data JPA Starter will derive those parameters from the datasource url string.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database= MYSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: I did create a project in https://start.spring.io with the only dependencies that you provided and I added spring data jpa but still the same thing i think the probleme is related to this line ''HHH000511: The 5.5.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no longer supported"

Comment: As I stated in my comment the problem is your dependencies which you decided to add. Remove them, your issue is not related to the line in your logging you are pointing to (to fix that remove `spring.jpa.database` property, and see that it still fails).

Comment: When i remove ```spring.jpa.database``` i cant use annotation @Entity

Answer (score 0):

Try with this dialect

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: when i use MySQL8Dialect i have this one : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead